# Generate last modified header for dynamic PHP page

Tags: php, function, shutdown

Is there a "normal" way of generating Last-Modified dates for (semi)dynamic PHP pages?

I am thinking of using get_included_files() to go through all of the included files checking the last mod date of each (in case any output generated by them may have changed).

There's no user specific output so that's not a factor - though there is a bit of text on the page that's a random testimonial.

And there's no database content so that's not a factor either.

Comment: imo, Questions to consider: What do you want to do if: 1) They haven't changed 2) They have changed? Would some sort of 'cache' software be useful? How much traffic do you have? How often is the semi dynamic page data changed? How much data would need to stored in the cache? What is the cost of generating any one page? Do you have any measured statistics for your web site as regards repeat pages against changed pages?

Comment: I just want to produce accurate Last-Modified headers. If the main page hasn't changed but and included page has then the output that's sent may differ, so the Last-Modified header should reflect that. Pages don't change often - less than weekly. Traffic is nominal. ie Not much. And with that amount of traffic I don't think cache software is warranted. The actual cost of generating a page isn't high - the front page for example does do much. I doubt that it even touches the database. The page uses Cache-Control and Expires headers already so this might not even be warranted. (?)